# How to configure Visual Studio for native C++ (unmanaged) development?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am completely new to C++ development and am trying to learn it in Visual Studio. How can I be sure that I am learning only C++ and not the managed extensions? What configuration settings do I need to change? What project types should I stick to? Any other advice?

**Side issue:**
I have tried turning off Language Extensions under

> Project properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Disable Language Extensions

but this has generated a compiler error:

> Error 1 Command line error D8016 : '/Za' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible

I've no idea what's going on here ..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The fact that you have `/clr` switch in there means you're using a .Net project type - you need to choose a "Win32" project type to get a pure C++ project.

Avoid anything calling itself "managed" or "CLR".

Answer (score 5):

In brief, all the Win32 C++ projects are native C++.

The ones including CLR in the name are managed C++.

Language extensions are nothing to do with .NET. It is a number of vendor-specific extensions to native C++. (So the effect of disabling language extensions is roughly similar specifying --ansi with the G++ compiler)

/clr is the flag you need to get rid of.

Answer (score 5):

So long as you stick to project types under "Win32" node in New Project dialog, you will only be dealing with native code. There's no way to accidentally write some managed code in those projects, unless you go into Project Properties and switch project type to managed.

Comment: I don't see a `Win32` node in the VS2017 `New Project` options, nor could I find anything in the installer options. Can you point me to how to get these project options please?

Comment: First of all, make sure that you have those components installed - in VS Installer, it's "desktop development with Visual C++": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=vs-2017. If you need MFC, you'll need to check that box in the details, as well.

The look under Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-1-create?view=vs-2017. You definitely don't have to worry about accidentally creating a managed app in VC++ these days, because C++/CLI has been deprecated a long time ago.

Comment: Seems I do have it installed, tho there is no `Win32` Node. BTW, I have VS2017 and C++/CLI is still available for installation AND I have it installed. Also, when I compile a very basic project - a DLL - I can use IL Disassembler to view the .NET IL, which I wouldn't expect to for a native compile. So I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: There is no Win32 node in newer releases of VS - it's called Windows Desktop now. If you have an *existing* project, then it will use whatever it was configured for when it was created. If you're creating a new project, C++/CLI project templates specifically say "CLR", so you must be picking one of those if you get a managed DLL as the output.